# how to show the submenu of each clicked menu item and not all in a react array

Tags: css, reactjs

Im using a data array to create a menu in react, the menu work fine but it has some submenu on determinated items.

I use the classnames to show the submenu, this is made in 2 separated components of react and the problem is the following, when I click on one menu item which has submenu all the submenus are open at the same time.

Not sure how to fix it and just open the corresponded submenu.

This is the menu:

```
export default class MainNavBarView_Profit extends React.Component {
    constructor (props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {active: false, activetest:false}
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({ active: !this.state.active, activetest: !this.state.activetest });
    }

    render() {
        var me = this;
        var cx = require('classnames');
        var button = cx ({
            'aui-profit-main-navbar-dropdown-closed-li' : true,
            'selected' : this.state.active
        });
        var menu_data = [
            { text: 'Inicio' },
            { text: 'Ventas' },
            { text: 'Gastos' },
            { text: 'Bancos' },
            { text: 'Invitar a mis amigos' },
            { text: 'Mi gestor', submenu: [
                { text: 'Conectar con mi gestor' },
                { text: 'Buscar un gestor' },
                { text: 'Ver ofertas de expertos' },
                { text: 'Buscar un experto' },
                ]
            },
            { text: 'Aplicaciones', submenu: [
                { text: 'Facturación' },
                { text: 'Contabilidad' },
                { text: 'Proyectos' },
                { text: 'Stock' },
                { text: '+ Añadir más aplicaciones' },
                ]
            }
        ];

        var menu_options = [];
        menu_data.map(function(menu_option, index) {
            if (menu_option.submenu) {
                menu_options.push(<li key={index} className={button}><a href="#" className="aui-profit-main-navbar-dropdown-closed-a" onClick={me.handleClick}>{menu_option.text}</a> <MainNavBarDropdownView options={menu_option.submenu} activetest={me.state.activetest} /></li>);
            } else {
                menu_options.push(<li key={index} className="aui-profit-main-navbar-li"><a href="#" className="aui-profit-main-navbar-a">{menu_option.text}</a></li>);
            }
        });

        return (
            <div className="aui-profit-main-navbar-container">
                <nav>
                    <ul className="aui-profit-main-navbar-ul">
                        {menu_options}
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is the submenu:

```
export default class MainNavBarDropdownView_Profit extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);   
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        if (process.env.BROWSER) {
            document.addEventListener("click", (e) => this._handleOnClickDocument(e), true);
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (process.env.BROWSER) {
            document.removeEventListener("click", (e) => this._handleOnClickDocument(e), true);
        }
    }

    _handleOnClickDocument(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (this.refs.dropdownContainer.getDOMNode().contains(e.target)) return;

        if(this.state.active == true){
            this.setState({ 
                active: false
            });
        }
    }

    render() {

        var submenu_options = [];
        this.props.options.map(function(submenu_option, index) {
            submenu_options.push(<li key={index} className="aui-profit-main-navbar-dropdown-li"><a href="#" className="aui-profit-main-navbar-dropdown-a">{submenu_option.text}</a></li>);
        });
        var cx = require('classnames');
        var dropdown = cx ({
            'aui-profit-main-navbar-dropdown-ul' : true,
            'block' : this.props.activetest
        });

        return (
            <ul className={dropdown} ref="dropdownContainer">
                {submenu_options}
            </ul>                   
        );
    }
}
```

I was wondering if I can do it just with css, adding a class to the items with submenu which displays or changes the ul class to block?

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: I tried but its not working on jsfiddle, we are using the ES6 with babel maybe jsfiddle not work with it.